# Bind AngularJS model into html comment for debug purposes

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, comments

I need to debug an object id. This kind of object appears many many times on my interface and using log would be difficult to track.

I want to be able to click on the specific object and with the inspector be able to see a comment with it's id. Basically put something like following on my template:

```
<!-- {{object.id}} -->
```

So it shows something like:

```
<!-- 182371923129837 -->
```

I'm trying exactly that, but on the html comment I just get:

```
<!-- {{object.id}} -->
```

Instead of the number I want to see. Tried searching first, but found nothing resembling this issue. What am I missing?

Comment: You can check the scope of an element using Batarang in Chrome or [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) in Firefox/Firebug.

Comment: I think this basically solves my core problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly, angular will not compile html comments, and even if you tried to generate the comment text yourself like contcating `{{"<!--"+ somedata +"-->"}}` it will not work and if you tried to trust it as html you can't bind to comment that's why you need to check this answer

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28245596/916952