# How can I insert an HTML comment with an interpolated expression?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to add an HTML comment with an interpolated expression within an ng-repeat block.  However, when I try to do this, the expression is not interpolated.  For example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items"
    <!-- ID that I don't want the user to see, but want for debugging = {{item.id}} -->
    <td>{{item.prettyName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.someProperty}}</td>
    <td>{{item.someOtherProperty}}</td>
</tr>
```

When I view the DOM (i.e. the Elements tab in Chrom DevTools), I just see the uninterpolated string ("{{item.id}}") instead of the interpolated value.

What's the correct syntax here?

Comment: What about using `display:none` or `ng-show`/`ng-hide` on a `div` or `span` or something?

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks - a little overkill for sure, but very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is way overkill, since you could just use the suggestions in the comments of `display: none` or similar, but just as a fun exercise:

The syntax to invoke a directive on a comment is:

```
<!-- directive: foo expression -->
```

I was hoping that something like `ng-bind` supported comments, but it doesn't. But you could easily create your own:

```
app.directive('comment', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'M',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var comment = $interpolate(attrs.comment)(scope);
      element.replaceWith("<!-- " + comment + "-->" );
    }
  };
});
```

And the usage is:

```
<!-- directive: comment "something something {{item.id}}" -->
```