# How do I use Angular 1.x template interpolation inside an HTML comment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I would like to populate an HTML comment with data from the scope.

Angular seems to ignore processing anything inside of an HTML comment.

For example, the following gets output verbatim in the rendered DOM, rather than interpolating the row in place.

```
<!-- Row id: {{ row.id }}  -->
```

I would like the output to be like so:

```
<!-- Row id: 19 -->
```

Comment: You cant bind things inside a commented out section of code. What is the goal of this?

Comment: I'd like to add some debug information inside the DOM that can be use used later for debugging. If it's not possible I can find another way, but this seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: You could also create divs with the debug code that are ng-if out. That would essentially create the comment for you.

Comment: ng-if won't work since angular doesn't render those blocks, but ng-show or ng-hide should work ok.

Comment: ng-show or hide will. I was suggesting the ng-if would work if you created the element in your javascript first then bound it to the dom.

Comment: I use something like  `<style>/* {{myDebugData}} */</style>` or a hidden element

Comment: What if you better use gulp to make that task ???

Comment: User New Dev has a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28245596/4797767