# Can an angular scope variable be rendered in an html comment?

Tags: html, angularjs

What I'm trying to do is render a comment in the source dynamically. Here is what I've tried:

In the controller:

```
$scope.releaseVersion = 'v4.1.0'
```

In the html

```
"<!-- Software {{releaseVersion}} -->"
```

But this just renders the unbound variable name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245278/how-can-i-insert-an-html-comment-with-an-interpolated-expression#answer-28245596